# Specify JobRepository Isolation Level with @EnableBatchProcessing

Tags: java, transactions, annotations, spring-batch

I am creating a Spring Batch application using Java annotations. I have the @EnableBatchProcessing annotation, so I haven't explicitly defined a JobRepository or JobRepositoryFactory. This was working fine until today, when I started getting the "ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction" error.

How can I change the isolation level on a JobRepository I don't create or interact with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"How can I change the isolation level on a JobRepository I don't create or interact with?"  In short, you don't.  You need to create it yourself by extending the `DefaultBatchConfigurer` and overriding the `createJobRepository` method to provide your own customized instance.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: (Sigh, I **hate** that enter adds the comment, rather than putting in a cr/lf.) Continuing what I was **trying** to say: But in order to actually set the isolation level, I have to do that on the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean`. To use that to create a `JobRepository` I have to set the `dataSource` on the factory bean, which is private to `DefaultBatchConfigurer`. So I would have to also override `setDataSource` and keep my own reference to the `dataSource`. I assume I should also **remove** `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation, since I am extending `DefaultBatchConfigurer` now. Correct?

Comment: The `BatchConfigurer` is used by `@EnableBatchProcessing` so you wouldn't want to delete it.  Also, yes, you'd either need to override setDataSource or autowire a separate reference in your own `BatchConfigurer`.

Comment: The problem has disappeared just as mysteriously as it arrived, without me having to do anything (except go home and come back the next day). Thanks for all the information.